# ASHX Image Download Saved as ASHX

Tags: c#, asp.net, content-type, ashx

When a user clicks my link it brings up the save as dialog, but it wants to save it as a ashx file in any other browser than IE. The file is standard jpeg that is being taken from a database. What would cause this to do?

```
       string id = ctx.Request.QueryString["id"];

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("EBig", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EID", id);

        byte[] pict = null;
        ctx.Response.ContentType = "image/pjpeg";
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            pict = (byte[])cmd.ExecuteScalar();

            ctx.Response.Clear();

            ctx.Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;");
            ctx.Response.ContentType = "image/pjpeg";
            ctx.Response.BinaryWrite(pict);
            ctx.Response.Flush();
            ctx.Response.End();
        }
        catch
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Hanselman has a post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheContentDispositionSagaControllingTheSuggestedFileNameInTheBrowsersSaveAsDialog.aspx) on this.  It involves setting an additional attribute named `filename` on your `Content-Disposition` response header.

The related [RFC is here](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1806.txt), relevant section is 2.3:

> The sender may want to suggest a filename to be used if the entity is
>      detached and stored in a separate file. If the receiving MUA writes
>      the entity to a file, the suggested filename should be used as a
>      basis for the actual filename, where possible.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the filename:

```
context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition",
    string.Format("attachment;filename={0}", yourFileName));
```